# Call javaScript Function Server Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serverside-javascript

I wrote this javascript Function  :

```
       function ShowMsg(msg) {
                $.blockUI({
            message: '<div dir=rtl align=center><h1><p>' + msg + '</p></h1></div>',
            css: { 
                border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
            }
        });

        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 



    }
```

i want to call this Function Server Side at asp.net :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType](), "script", "ShowMsg(" & "Saved" & ");", True)
```

But it does not work.
the function is work without argument.
is there any syntax error exist?
thanks

Comment: Check how the server prints your JS code to the client.

Comment: Right click in your browser, and click view source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Saved' parameter is missing the quotes

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType](), "script", "ShowMsg('" & "Saved" & "');", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

These kind of errors you can check through javascript debugging. to enable javascript debugging. 
go to : tools > intenet options > advanced > browsing and uncheck (disable script debugging). 
in Internet Explorer Browser
. then you can attach debugger by writing debugger; @ any location in javascript function egs:

function ShowMsg(msg) {
         *

- **debugger;**

*
                $.blockUI({
            message: '

## ' + msg + '

',
            css: { 
                border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
            }
        });

```
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 



}
```